# Alternative of addToJavaScriptWindowObject in Qt 5.12.4

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I am trying to migrate my code from QWebView to QWebEngine. I want to add an object from my code into the javascript. In QWebView it was possible with the function addToJavaScriptWindowObject. How can we do this in QWebEngine.

webview->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("qtObject", this);

**Our java script need to call functions of "qtObject".**

Comment: use QtWebChannel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QFile webChannelJsFile(":/qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js");
    if (!webChannelJsFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug() << QString("Couldn't open qwebchannel.js file: %1").arg(webChannelJsFile.errorString());
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "OK webEngineProfile";
        QByteArray webChannelJs = webChannelJsFile.readAll();
        webChannelJs.append(
            "\n"
            "var qtObject"
            "\n"
            "new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {"
            "     qtObject = channel.objects.qtObject;"
            "});"
        );

        QWebEngineScript script;
        script.setName("qwebchannel.js");
        script.setInjectionPoint(QWebEngineScript::DocumentCreation);
        script.setRunsOnSubFrames(false);
        script.setWorldId(QWebEngineScript::MainWorld);
        script.setSourceCode(webChannelJs);

        page->scripts().insert(script);

    QWebChannel *channel = new QWebChannel(page);
    channel->registerObject("qtObject", this);
    page->setWebChannel(channel);
    return page;
```